# For $n\ge4$, prove that $1!+2!+\cdots+n!$ cannot be the square of a positive integer

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I'm trying to prove this by induction but seem to be getting nowhere.

Comment: Can you write down the values for $n = 4,5,6,7$, say, and look if you see a pattern?

Comment: @Oliver Why you hate low dots :(

Comment: @user2345215 \cdots for a series, \ldots for a sequence. :P

Comment: @user87347 Are you familiar with modular arithmetic?

Answer (score 11):

Every square is either $0,1$ or $4\,\bmod 5$,. For $k\ge 5$ we have $k!\equiv 0\bmod 5$ hence for $n\ge 4$
$$1!+2!+\cdots+n!\equiv 1!+2!+3!+4!\equiv 33\equiv 3\mod 5$$
thus it cannot be a square.

Comment: Nice solution, but how do I know that every square is either 0, 1 or 4 mod 5 ? I wrote out some squares and I see that this is cyclical... is that enough?

Comment: @grayQuant That's how it works. A formal proof that it depends only on the equivalence class mod $5$ is that $$(x+5y)^2=x^2+2\cdot 5xy+25y^2\equiv x^2\bmod 5$$

Comment: @AlexBecker +1. I would like to add that a nice generalization of this is that every square is a square mod any integer.